how to get dropdown selection in order to save it in a database
In my html, I created a table and I fetched in data from a DB. The goal of this table is to give scholar opinion for each student so I created a select dropdown list for each type of school with differents opinions option.
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
        <th>BTS</th>
        <th>IUT</th>
        <th>Licence</th>
        <th>CPGE</th>
        <th>Ecole</th>
    </tr>
<!-- PHP CODE TO FETCH DATA FROM ROWS -->
<?php 
// LOOP TILL END OF DATA
while($rows=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
?>
    <tr>
        <!-- FETCHING DATA FROM EACH
            ROW OF EVERY COLUMN -->
        <td><?php echo $rows['NOM'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['PRENOM'];?></td>
        <td><select name="Avis" id="avis_BTS" onchange="change()">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="Avis" id="avis_IUT" onchange="change()">>
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="Avis" id="avis_Licence" onchange="change()">>
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="Avis" id="avis_CPGE" onchange="change()">>
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="Avis" id="avis_Ecole" onchange="change()">>
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>

I also created a java script file butit doesn't work
Import in the html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Avis Terminales</title>

JS file
// Initialisation des variables
var avis = "";

// fonction pour bien montrer visuellement au professeur que e choix a été validé
function change() 
{
    if(document.getElementsByID("avis_BTS").value != ""){
        document.getElementById("avis_BTS").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}

// Pour récuperer les avis et les mettres dans une variable pour chaque élève
function save() 
{
    //var avis_bts = document.getElementById("avis_BTS").value;
    // document.write(avis_bts);
    //document.write(5+6);

    let selection = document.getElementById('avis_BTS');
    if(selection.selectedIndex == 1){
        a = "Très Favorable";
    }
    else if(selection.selectedIndex == 2){
        a = "Favorable";
    }
    else{
        a = "Avis";
    }

    document.getElementById('reponse2').innerHTML = "hello";
}

Nothing change on my web page

IDs need to be unique, but with the output you are creating in your loop there, yours won't be - so that is the very first thing you need to fix here.

No errors in your browser console? getElementsByID is a typo!

@CBroe do you know how to fix it ?

@brombeer no errors in my browser console but thanks, I fixed it

It's a bit hard to tell what you actually want to achieve here (and comments in the code in French, aren't particularly helpful either.) Right now, we can't even see where that save function would be called.

@brombeer Yeah it's very strange. I think there is a real problem between my browser and my code

@CBroe save function is for getting the values from the table in order to save the changes for each students in the database. The function is being called when you click on the button "Valider"

Delegation will help if you need to handle the change on each select.
As already mentioned, IDs need to be unique. If you remove the inline change, add thead and tbody and have something like this, the IDs are not used by the script.
If you change id to data-avisid, your HTML is valid and you can get the avis using select.dataset.avisid instead.
Alternatively change the names of the selects to match the avis.


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('table tbody');
  const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  table.addEventListener('change', (e) => { // on change of any select
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches('select[name=Avis')) return; // not a select
    const avis = Array.from(rows).map(row => {
      const name = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'))
        .slice(0, 2)
        .map(cell => cell.textContent)
        .join(', '); // name
      const avis = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('select'))
        .map(select => ({ [select.dataset.avisid]: select.value }));
      return { "Nom": name, avis };
    });
    console.log(avis); // here you can AJAX the values
  });
});
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
      <th>BTS</th>
      <th>IUT</th>
      <th>Licence</th>
      <th>CPGE</th>
      <th>Ecole</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nom1</td>
      <td>Prenom1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_BTS">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_IUT">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_Licence">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_CPGE">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_Ecole">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nom2</td>
      <td>Prenom2</td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_BTS">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_IUT">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_Licence">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_CPGE">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_Ecole">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nom3</td>
      <td>Prenom3</td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_BTS">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_IUT">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_Licence">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_CPGE">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Avis" data-avisid="avis_Ecole">
          <option value="">Avis</option>
          <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
          <option value="F">Favorable</option>
          <option value="R">Réservé</option>
          <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>



Same code but using a submit button


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('table tbody');
  const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  document.getElementById('avisForm').addEventListener('submit', (e) => { // submitting
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the submit
    const avis = Array.from(rows).map(row => {
      const name = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'))
        .slice(0, 2)
        .map(cell => cell.textContent)
        .join(', '); // name
      const avis = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('select'))
        .map(select => ({ [select.name]: select.value }));
      return { "Nom": name, avis };
    });
    console.log(avis); // here you can AJAX the values
  });
});
<form id="avisForm">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
        <th>BTS</th>
        <th>IUT</th>
        <th>Licence</th>
        <th>CPGE</th>
        <th>Ecole</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nom1</td>
        <td>Prenom1</td>
        <td>
          <select name="BTS">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="IUT">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Licence">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="CPGE">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Ecole">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nom2</td>
        <td>Prenom2</td>
        <td>
          <select name="BTS">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="IUT">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Licence">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="CPGE">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Ecole">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nom3</td>
        <td>Prenom3</td>
        <td>
          <select name="BTS">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="IUT">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Licence">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="CPGE">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Ecole">
            <option value="">Avis</option>
            <option value="TF">Très Favorable</option>
            <option value="F">Favorable</option>
            <option value="R">Réservé</option>
            <option value="D">Défavorable</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Sauvegarder" />
</form>



